# Onchage checkbox show or hide this

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, hide, show

I need to show or hide an element on change checkbox.

```
<div class="y">
    <div class="x"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
</div>

<div class="y">
    <div class="x"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
</div>

<div class="y">
    <div class="x"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" />
</div>
```

If the user clicks in the first check I want to show or hide the first div "x", and the same thing for second, third, etc, got it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"].myCheck').on('change', function() {
    var target = $(this).prev('div.x');
    if (this.checked) target.show();
    else target.hide();
});
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. That's exactly what i'm searching. Really thanks! ;D

Comment: @IsmaelUssefatt welcome. Hope you will accept that also.